# How to use while loop to find intersection point of values

Tags: r

I am new here and to R.

The problem is such where Par1 (person 1) and Par2 (person 2) initially start out with $400, and $120 , respectively in the stock market. Par1 will increase its income at 10%/day, whereas Par2 at 20%/day. I figured out how to write out an loop equation to fill in the gains for 30 days.  However, I want to use a "while loop and print command" to find the day when Par2 gains are no longer less than Par 1.

In summary:
Par1 starts with $400, has 10% gains/day
Par2 starts with $120, has 20% gains/day

Using a while loop and print function, when will Par2 surpass Par1. Thank you!!

CODE USED TO FIGURE OUT DAILY GAINS FOR EACH PAR (PERSON) FOR 30 DAYS

```
 rm(list=ls())        #removes any lists from the workspace
    graphics.off()    #clears any graphics

   Par1=rep(0,30);    #sets vector of 30 zeros
   Par1[1]=400        #fill first position with 400
     Par2=rep(0,30);  #sets vector of 30 zeros
      Par2[1]=120     #fill first position with 120


   for (n in 2:30)              #For time points 2 through 30 (days 2 through 30)

 {                              #Start loop

       Par1[n]=Par1[n-1]*1.10   #Formula that calculates daily gains by 10%

         Par2[n]=Par2[n-1]*1.20 #Formula that calculates daily gains by 20%

  }                             #End loop
```

I need a while loop and print command to find when Par2>Par1, something like this:

```
  while (Par2<Par1) 
     {  "commands" 
         }
      print("day")
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a while loop?

```
floor(log(400/120)/log(1.2/1.1) + 1)
```

Note: indexing here is 0-based, meaning the initial day where they have $400 and $120 is considered day 0.

Answer (score 1):

Type in `Par2 < Par1` into the console after running your first piece of code. See that you get back a logical vector. Finding `while` of a logical vector isn't what you want.

Look into the `which` command, to extract the indices of `TRUE` values from a logical vector. I think you might get close to what you want with:

```
> min(which(Par2 > Par1))
[1] 15
```

Note also that the first part of your code isn't very R-like. I get the same results replacing your entire first section with

```
Par1 <- 400*(1.10)^(0:29)
Par2 <- 120*(1.20)^(0:29)
```

which you can verify using `all.equal`. That is only one of the possible ways to construct your variables using vectorized operations and avoiding `for`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions.  The reason I was requesting a "while loop" is because this is for a class -- that was the assignment.  I was able to figure it out... as has tended to be the case so far in learning R, I was over-complicating things.  Here's the answer I landed on:

```
> rm(list=ls())         #removes any lists from the workspace
> graphics.off()        #clears any graphics 
> Par1=400              #Sets Par1 at 400
> Par2=120              #Sets Par2 at 120
> day=1                 #Begin sumulation on day 1
> while (Par2<Par1)     #While Par2 is less than Par1
> {                     #begins loop
>  Par1=Par1*1.10       #Par1 gains 10% per day
>  Par2=Par2*1.20       #Par2 gains 20% per day
>  day=day+1            #Cycle throuh one day at a time
>}                      #Closes loop
>print(day)             #Output the day that Par2 surpasses Par1
```